# Xamarin Forms & Parse SDK - How to edit the server address

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin.forms

I'm currently, with some friends, on a freelance project. For some reasons, the customer asked us to don't make a new server but just use **[Parse](https://parseplatform.github.io/)**. The thing is, we knew that Parse will stop but he was keep wanting this thing, so we used it. Today, Parse has been stop and the costumer said he moved the data/stuff on another server. He also told us; "you just have to change the server address."

However, I can't find the way to change this address from xamarin forms. I found a solution which doesn't exist on my side:

```
ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
{
    ApplicationId = "MYAPPID",
    Server = "http://example.com/parse/"
});
```

But I as said above, it doesn't work since Initialize takes only 2 params which are the following, and not a `ParseClient.Configuration` stuff.

So I would like to know if you have any idea? It's not the only thing I tried but it seems to be the best example I can show you.

Any help is welcome, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started to use Parse. So maybe I can help you.
In fact with Xamarin Forms applications, Parse's configuration is a little bit different than with native platforms.

I suspect you don't use correct Parse DLL in your project. For instance in your iOS app (AppDelegate.cs), reference Parse.iOS.dll. Personally, I don't use Nuget packages and downloaded the correct DLLs from here:
[Parse SDK .NET (github)](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/releases/tag/1.7.0)

So referencing this dll in your project, you should be able to initialize Parse like that:

```
ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
{
     ApplicationId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b1782265ea00",
     Server = "http://myParseServer.com/Parse/",
     WindowsKey = parseID
});
```

**For a more detailed description on how to use Parse for Xamarin Forms**, I wrote a Post describing my solution:
[Setup Parse for Xamarin Forms, conditional builds](https://kampeki-factory.blogspot.fr/2017/05/parse-for-xamarin-forms-no-pcl-my.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, because i was working with some friends, we finaly found that we weren't using the good paquet.. Thank !